# Save find command output as a colon separated environment variable

Tags: bash

I have what I thought was a trivial issue, where I wanted to turn find output into a PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. I cant understand why the following bash snippet fails:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`find /usr/loc* /usr/X11 -name pkgconfig`
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH// /:}
```

I guess it isnt really a space that is separating the different strings. But what is it? After lots of messing around I ended up with:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`echo $(find /usr/loc* /usr/X11 -name pkgconfig ) | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

which works, but I feel it is ugly and clumsy. Any improvements?

Comment: It's a newline. `${PKG_CONFIG_PATH//$'\n'/:}`

Comment: ...if you look at the output of `find`, you'll see that it's newlines separating lines. Why would you think it would be spaces? (If you're using `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to look at the value, then it's `echo` putting the spaces there: When you don't use double quotes around your variables they get string-split and passed to `echo` as individual arguments, and then `echo` separates its arguments with spaces).

Comment: Hmmm,  I had tried `${PKG_CONFIG_PATH//\n/:}` etc. By the way this is with the bash shell.

Comment: `\n` is two characters, a backslash and an n; `$'\n'` is (well, parses to) only one character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell GNU `find` to use a colon directly, and then trim it with a parameter expansion available in any POSIX shell:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(find /usr/loc* /usr/X11 -name pkgconfig -printf '%p:')
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH%:} # trim last colon
```

...or properly replace the newlines in the output from `find` (note that this is extended syntax not available in pure POSIX shells):

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(find /usr/loc* /usr/X11 -name pkgconfig)
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH//$'\n'/:}
```

Comment: Instead of your second method doing two steps, you could imply pipe into `tr '\n' ':'`

Comment: @Mr.Llama, but why in the world would you use an external command for that? Sure, `tr` is faster for really large streams, but this isn't likely to be big enough to cancel out its startup costs.

Comment: Oh -- for POSIX compatibility. Right. Not worrying here since the question is tagged bash.

Comment: This is for the bash shell. I had not seen the new-fangled '-printf' argument before and nether has my OS: 'find: -printf: unknown option'. Thanks all for the very quick responses.

Comment: As I say in the answer, it requires GNU find.